# Special characters like @ and & in cURL POST data

Tags: post, curl

How do I include special characters like @ and & in the cURL POST data? I'm trying to pass a name and password like:

```
curl -d name=john passwd=@31&3*J https://www.mysite.com
```

This would cause problems as `@` is used for loading files and `&` for specifying more than one key/value. Is there some way I can escape these characters? `\@` and `\&` don't seem to work.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

cURL > 7.18.0 has an option [`--data-urlencode`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) which solves this problem. Using this, I can simply send a POST request as

```
curl -d name=john --data-urlencode passwd=@31&3*J https://www.example.com
```

Summarizing the comments, in case of mixed "good" and "bad" data and exclamation marks inside we can use on Windows:

```bash
curl -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=super-client&acr_values=tenant:TNT123" --data-urlencode "client_secret=XxYyZ21D8E&%fhB6kq^mXQDovSZ%Q*!ipINme" https://login.example.com/connect/token
```

Comment: I have 7.52.1 and I can't get this to work...  I can do --data-urlencode "something=it's a test" but not with double quotes or @ symbols...

Comment: Remember to use `--data-urlencode` only for the data part that needs it. For example, the following will not work when you combine the data into one entity: `curl --data-urlencode "name=john&passwd=@31&3*J" https://www.example.com`

Comment: Exclamation points seem to cause problems with this in regards to history expansion in bash. You can fix it with single quotes around each piece of data (e.g. `--data-urlencode 'password=abc!123'` or by escaping the exclamation `--data-urlencode password=abc\!123`.
More info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33339/cant-use-exclamation-mark-in-bash

Answer (score 46):

How about using the entity codes...

`@ = %40`

`& = %26`

So, you would have:

`curl -d 'name=john&passwd=%4031%263*J' https://www.mysite.com`

Comment: Could you please be kind enough to specify entity code for "+"

Comment: did you figure out the '+' part for this?

Comment: I wanted to replace name=john&passwd=%4031%263*J with an variable, but couldn't. Any help?

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya '+' is '%2B'. You can use https://www.urlencoder.io/ if you'd like to encode any character.

Comment: works only on formurlencoded buyt does not work on json post data.

Answer (score 16):

Double quote (" ") the entire `URL`. It works.

```bash
curl "http://www.example.com?name=john&passwd=@31&3*J"
```

Comment: The request is supposed to be a POST, not a GET.

Answer (score 14):

Just found another solutions worked for me. You can use '\' sign before your one special.

```
passwd=\@31\&3*J
```

Answer (score 8):

If password has the special characters in it, just round the password with the single quote it will work.

```bash
curl -u username:'this|!Pa&*12' --request POST https://www.example.com
```

Comment: This worked for me for a password that had a double quote (`"`) in it.

Comment: the same can be done with username: `curl -u 'weird|user!':'this|!Pa&*12' --request POST https://www.example.com`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```bash
export CURLNAME="john:@31&3*J"
curl -d -u "${CURLNAME}" https://www.example.com
```

Comment: Does not work if the exclamation point ("!") is one of the special characters.

Answer (score -1):

I did this

```
~]$ export A=g

~]$ export B=!

~]$ export C=nger


   curl http://<>USERNAME<>1:$A$B$C@<>URL<>/<>PATH<>/
```