# Using the character % in cURL POST data

Tags: url, post, curl

I learned from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060093/special-characters-like-and-in-curl-post-data) that I can use entity codes for characters like `@ = %40`
`& = %26` but I can't find how to include a `%`.

For example, I want to do the below command but it errors because of the `%`. Is there a way to escape it?

```
curl -d 'name=foo&description=bar has a 25% discount' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything encoded should be %[two-digit hexadecimal of its byte value], which makes '%' to encode to %25.

curl also features the command line option [--data-urlencode](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

`% = %25`

This tool was helpful in discovering how to encode it: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ which does the following in JavaScript:

```
 function encode() {
   var obj = document.getElementById('dencoder');
   var unencoded = obj.value;
   obj.value = encodeURIComponent(unencoded).replace(/'/g,"%27").replace(/"/g,"%22");   
 }
```